# Redirect python interactive help()

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I'm working on a interactive python shell for an application using Qt.  However I can't seem to get the interactive help to redirect.  I have this in my python code:

```
class OutputCatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ''
    def write(self, stuff):
        self.data += stuff

sys.stdout = OutputCatcher()
```

However when ever I run help() it doesn't redirect the interactive help, it just dumps it out to the console where I ran the python script from.  If I press ctrl+c in the console it then sends it to my OutputCatcher object.

I did try google but couldn't really find anything.

Comment: What platform is the code supposed to run on?  Do you need to run the console inside the current Python interpreter, or is it possible to launch a subprocess?

Comment: Platform would be Linux, Windows and OSX, so pretty much anything :)

Comment: OK, what about my second question?  Is it feasible to just run a Python interactive interpreter in a subprocess, or do you need access to the current interpreters variables from inside the interactive interpreter?

Comment: Yeah I need to access variables, it's part of a larger C++ project.  The python console just gives access to the public API of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to guess what help is doing, just read the source.

The `help` builtin is create in site.py, it's an instance of class `_Helper`. When called it simply delegates the call through to `pydoc.help(...)` the source for which you'll find in pydoc.py.

```
class _Helper(object):
    """Define the built-in 'help'.
    This is a wrapper around pydoc.help (with a twist).

    """

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Type help() for interactive help, " \
               "or help(object) for help about object."
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        import pydoc
        return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)
```

pydoc.help is an instance of `pydoc.Helper` with input/output set to `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, but (and I suspect this is where you have your problem) it uses the value of stdin/stdout at the time when pydoc is imported so later rebinding them won't have any effect.

I suggest you replace the builtin help instance with your own _Helper class that creates a fresh pydoc Helper explicitly with whatever files you need.

Answer (score 2):

Help doesn't just dump to stdout, but interacts with the terminal. It also is never meant to be used outside of the shell, so it wouldn't be written to guarantee such things work.

What you are trying to do is implement a terminal and that is a non-trivial task, but there are probably existing terminal emulation libraries for Qt. Possibly even written in Python and surely with bindings.

Comment: `python -c "help()"` > file` dumps the help to `file` for me -- so it does seem to interact with stdout.  It just does not use `sys.stdout`, but you can hack your way around this.  I'm just waiting for Nathan to answer my questions :)